# connect Docker Superset to a Windows Local Database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, apache-superset

on my Windows 10, I have Apache-Superset container running on Docker Desktop.
and also I have installed PostgreSQL ver.12 and myQSL ver.8 too.
**now, in the SQLAlchemy I cannot connect to any of them! adding a Database/Datasource**
I've tried many ways, in Superset Doc(s) and other forum suggestions too.

> postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbName
>
> postgresql://username:password@127.0.01:5432/dbName
>
> mysql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbName
>
> mysql://username:password@127.0.01:5432/dbName

**every time I get this error:**
*ERROR: Connection failed, please check your connection settings.*

I just need an empty Database to be able to add a CSV file to.
**many Thanks! in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

this is definitely a complex and unique setup! (Superset isn't supported on Windows, so Docker is definitely the way to go if you need to use Windows).

The main thing to understand is that the networking for your windows database server is different from the network within Docker. This is a common confusion actually, but Docker has some escape hatches for you:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Answer (score 1):

### **this is the Solution!**

instead of `"LocalHost"` or `"127.0.0.1"` for addressing the Database-M.S.
you should put this:  `"host.docker.internal"`

### that's all.